# List Index Is Out of Range

Tags: python, list

I am trying to parse through a data file to pull numbers from the data file. I was given this solution earlier (below) which worked. But once I moved the python script from Windows to Mac, I started getting a list index is out of range error. Any ideas?

```
with open("Fdeg.dat", "r+") as f:
    numbers = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in f]
```

Comment: obviously line.split() has no element at index 2

Comment: If it does this with the exact same file on both systems, I'm mystified. If the files aren't identical, then there's your answer.

Comment: Without looking at your file, your code looks fine.

Comment: Does it help if you change the mode to `"r+U"`?

Comment: Different versions of Python? Unicode?

Comment: @DSM I'd suspect line endings if it worked on Mac but not Windows, but it's the other way around.

Comment: Change your script to print the `repr()` of each line in the file before splitting it and see if there's a difference between what is shown on each system.

Comment: @PeterWood The code I'm working with on windows has unicode encoding specified whereas on the Mac I believe it is not specified. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @user3885927 No it does have an element because it reads each line in the document. Like I said, this works on one machine but not the other.

Comment: @martineau I'm sorry could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by that? What does the "repr()" function do?

Comment: If you print with `repr(line)` it makes it completely unambiguous what is contained within the string, including unprintable characters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying for me @Mark. DeeWBee: Note, you won't be able to use the list comprehension if you do this because the `for line in f` in it is incompatible — but this just a temporary measure to help determine what's different between the two systems.